# Error by including drawable xml-file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Hello community,
I want to iclude different drawable xml-files into my activity_main.xml
However,when I want to includ following code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
      <size
         android:layout_height="110dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

the name is button_height.xml into my main-file:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/cmda1"
                 android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="@drawable/button_height" />
```

It does not work and Eclipse says only:

> You must supply a layout_height attribute.
>   and
>   error in an XML file: aborting build.

I searched an answer in the internet but dont found one.
But I think its an easy mistake lots of people are doing.

so, I hope for usefull answers
and sorry for my awful english.

Comment: @drawable/button_height would be a drawable type, you have to pass in a string similar to "110dp" as you did in layout_width

Answer (score 2):

Your whole idea of drawable, selector and dimension is messed up. Can't put height in selector and also selectors (which are drawable) as height.

Do this.

**If you want to use xml to get height**

Add a file in res folder with name *res/values/dimens.xml* and add this line in that

```
<resources>
    <integer name="btn_cmda_height" >110dp</integer>
</resources>
```

and change the button `cmda1` height property as

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_cmda_height"
```

Make it dynamic for various screen sizes by creating these files which will hold different values. Although this is the old way.

Read more about new way to do this [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

```
res/values/dimens.xml    
res/values-small/dimens.xml    
res/values-normal/dimens.xml    
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

**If you don't want to use xml to get height**

just do this `android:layout_height="110dp"` in the button `cmda1` height property

**NOTE:**
Your selector code is wrong and not required at all. Selectors are used to define the background state of a view

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, but i know how to write it direkt into my xml file. but is your solution dynamic for different display dimensions ?